# How to completely erase Windows 7 and install Ubuntu instead?

Tags: windows, xubuntu

I just got a new computer with Windows 7 on it and want to install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) instead. I think I previously need to erase completely Windows from it and then replace it by Xubuntu, but I don't know how to proceed.

Has anybody some procedure to give me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you don't. Boot from the installation media, start the installation and at some point you'll be asked what to do. Select "Erase and Install...".

Comment: I wonder why is this question downvoted. Is it just because it's a possible duplicate? And if it is, so what? The OP is a novice. Shouldn't we welcome newcomers and show some tolerance towards their (possible) faults?

Comment: I would recommend using dual-boot rather than "jumping in" to Ubuntu. Plus erasing all your windows data files might be regretted a day, a week or a month later. @CristianaNicolae yes I agree. +1.